# Find count of employees who have applied for timeoff

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, ms-access-2010

Below are 3 columns I have in my table along with 4 other columns.

```
ID  EMP_ID  APPROVAL_STATUS
103 0023946 Pending
105 0025830 Pending
109 0022786 Pending
111 0023946 Pending
```

**My question:** What is the query to count the number of employees planning to take timeoff?

Keep in mind employee with id 0023946 has applied timeoff 2 times but still it should count has 1 and the rest add to the total value.

**The query I wrote in ASP:**

```
SELECT COUNT(*), EMP_ID 
FROM TimeoffDetails 
WHERE APPROVAL_STATUS = 'Pending' 
GROUP BY EMP_ID
```

Actual result should be 3 employees taking timeoff.  But above query is resulting 1 in asp whereas I ran this query in the database and it is resulting as 3.

Please help me to find the solution.

Comment: Can you update your question to include what you expect the result to look like?

Comment: Result should 3. But my above query is resulting with 1.

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: MicroSoft Access DB 2010

Comment: If i use DISTINCT it is giving systax error message to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this works :

```
SELECT Count(*) AS count_employee FROM (SELECT DISTINCT EMP_ID FROM timeoffdetails);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Pradip. With the help of your SQL query i could able to solve my problem. Below is the final query

SELECT Count(*) AS count_employee FROM (SELECT DISTINCT EMP_ID FROM TimeoffDetails WHERE APPROVAL_STATUS='Pending')

Answer (score 0):

You could use a DISTINCT COUNT (For a single total value you don't need to use GROUP BY):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT EMP_ID) FROM table_name TimeoffDetails WHERE APPROVAL_STATUS='Pending'
```

or with your GROUP BY:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT EMP_ID), EMP_ID FROM table_name TimeoffDetails WHERE APPROVAL_STATUS='Pending' GROUP BY EMP_ID
```

Comment: I get error message 

Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80040e14' 

Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'COUNT(DISTINCT EMP_ID)'. 

/OvertimeTrackingApp/ListEmp.asp, line 59

EMP_ID is a text filed in DB. I have kept as text coz emp_id can be alpha numeric.